# MS Access 2007: Runtime error 64224: Method 'Collect' of object 'recordset2' failed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been searching high and low for a workaround for this error, but since I haven't, I now turn to you for help. I am not (at all) an experienced programmer, so I hope this is not too basic a question to ask here, and that others can still benefit.

I am trying to set up a form, where I can register when one of our employees lends some stuff for a given period of time. I.e. from 21-12-2015 to 10-01-2016 employee n.n. lends a laptop. The form has two unbound textboxes TxtFraDato and TxtTilDato for the dates (from and to), and two unbound listboxes containing the name of the employee and the 'stuff' to be lend. The listboxes get their data from the tables:

Medarbejder (The employee):
- Navn: text (Primary key)

Materiale:
- Id: number (Primary key)
- ModelType: Text

I know that having a table like my Medarbejder-table is not at all pretty, and I have a fealing that this could be causing the problem, but this table is linked to a .txt-file created from a bat-file, and I have not been able to figure out, if there is another way to create such a link, that will give me a chance to give the table another primary key.

Finally, I have a button that on-click should save the record to the table "Udlaan":
Id: number (Primary key)
FraDato: date
TilDato: date
Medarbejder: text (lookup column)
Materiale: number (lookup column)

However, when I click the button, I get the runtime error 64224: Method 'Collect' of object 'recordset2' failed.

```
Private Sub btnSaveUdlaan_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim FraDato As Date
    Dim TilDato As Date
    Dim Medarbejder As String
    Dim Model As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Udlaan")

    FraDato = Me.TxtFraDato.Value
    TilDato = Me.TxtTilDato.Value
    Medarbejder = Me.MAList.Column(0)
    Model = Me.ModelList.Column(0)

    AddUdlaan rs, FraDato, TilDato, Medarbejder, Model

    rs.Close
    db.Close

End Sub
```

The AddUdlaan:

```
Private Sub AddUdlaan(rs As Recordset, FraDato As Date, _
    TilDato As Date, Medarbejder As String, Model As Integer)

    ' Adds a new record to a Recordset using the data passed
    ' by the calling procedure.

    With rs
        .AddNew
        !FraDato = FraDato
        !TilDato = TilDato
        **!Medarbejder** = Medarbejder ß The debugger is pointing to this field
        !Materiale = Model
        .Update

    End With

End Sub
```

Perhaps this is not at all the right way to solve by problem, so any help on this is much appreciated. But as it is, I would also be happy to lean something from the encounter with this error.

Comment: Consider replacing lookup fields with foreign keys relating to other tables. See their [evils](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the lookup field is a recordset of the recordset. Only Recordset2 can handle these.

Thus, what you should assign is the (hidden) `Id` of `Medarbejder`, in pseudo code:

```
 !Medarbejder = <Id of recordset Medarbejder>
```

This can be done but - as already mentioned by @Parfait - do yourself a favour and get rid of the lookup fields. How "smart" they may seem, they will cause you nothing than trouble in the future.

As a start, change table `Medarbejder` to have an *AutoNumber* `Id` as the *primary key*.

Comment: I am well aware that lookup fields is perhaps not "smart" smart, but it will keep the record of employees updated forever, without the user having to update it manually everyday, with the risk of mis-typing and so forth. And without the possibility to add an AutoNumber Id-field, the name of the employee IS the foreign key. But I will change the "Materiale"-lookup to a foreign key-reference. Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: Lookup fields can't _keep the record of employees updated forever, without the user having to update it manually everyday,_ ... In fact, lookup fields can't do anything you can't do otherwise. It is just a "superuser" feature to please those coming from Excel, but it is in every aspect a dead-end or a trap.